# Can I keep a 12 V lead-acid battery plugged in continuously?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, ups, lead-acid

I want to use the battery as a backup to a security camera that requires 9 VDC input. Can I keep the charger (12 V, 1 A or 14 V, 1.7 A) continuously plugged in to the battery and supply 9 V to the camera by a 12 V to 9 V step-down board?

Attaching images of the things used:

[image: Lead Acid Battery]

[image]

Comment: Why not check out how a UPS looks after batteries?

Comment: @SolarMike I have a PC UPS I tried but it did not last even 15 mins and DC ups/router UPS last about 2-4 hours. I have connected 12v to 9v step down board and the camera lasted for 8 hours on the battery. So was hoping if I could somehow make a DC UPS, please help out if you can
Thanks

Comment: You may want to check how much power your camera draws.  A good UPS has a good battery management system, that's hard to replicate in a one-off.  Probably the easiest way to make a good DC UPS is a plain old AC-out UPS and a wall-wart.  If it doesn't last long enough, get one with more capacity, or get a professional one that uses a separate battery and size the battery according to your load's requirements.

Comment: So what if the power goes out? The recorder and all the other parts in the system needs backup source too, not just the camera.

Comment: Non deep-cycle eg automotive type lead acid batteries can be floated in the manner you suggest. Battery manufacturers provide float voltage figures for their batteries. 15V Is too high.13.5 - maybe 13.8v is ok. Battery university is an excellent resource. Here is a [battery university lead acid battery charging page](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-403-charging-lead-acid)

Comment: Note you want the FLOAT voltage. Above page says " ... The recommended float voltage of most flooded lead acid batteries is 2.25V to 2.27V/cell."

Comment: @Justme Its a wifi camera, Tapo C320WS, recording is done in a SD card

Comment: Kept 12V 1Amp charger continuously connected to the Battery and connected 9V input security camera with step down board. It worked, the battery kept showed voltage 12.3v beginning and end of my test. Had kept plugged in for about a day. Not sure whether keeping this setup for long term will work. Thinking of using a battery charger board, will start charging once battery hits 9V and stop once it is charged. Any suggestions ?

Comment: **12.3V is too low !!!** The battery will sulphate and be damaged relatively quickly. As I noted above, you need about 13.5V to float the battery longer term. Jan Eerland's answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is a deal breaker, you need a charger that will resume charging when the battery needs it and that is capable of supplying the camera and charging the battery at the same time.

consider using an alarm power supply.

Comment: This might mean that it will automatically stop charging when full, but if it is connected to a load, it may resume charging at some point. Try measuring current at the battery terminals with load connected, and see if the charger can maintain current into the load without depleting the battery. If the load is less than 1.7A it should work.

Comment: I am going to try it out, just wanted an opinion on it as I am not sure what could happen

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to have the battery on standby and to power the security camera only when mains power is down. Battery life would thus increase to a considerable extent.

Here's a simpler solution utilising a standard AC-DC open frame power supply with battery charger (UPS function), available from a reputed SMPS manufacturer.

[image]

The 9 V DC regulator is normally fed by the power supply, with the battery taking over only when mains power is down.

Comment: 13.8V may be somewhat on the high side. Closer to 13.5-13.6V is usually in order for floating - but the answer is otherwise good.

Comment: @Russell McMahon - Thanks for the feedback, Russel.